# Table/Card fill up the remaining portion of screen

Tags: css, angular-material, angular7

The default shows the first 10 records and there is a couple inches of white space under the table.

How can I modify this so card/table takes up the rest of the screen and the pagination links are at the very botton bottom?

```
<mat-card>
<mat-card-content>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSortStart="desc" class="mat-elevation-z6">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="virtualMachineName">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
      Virtual Machine Name
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.virtualMachineName }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Status</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.status }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="labName">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Lab Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.labName }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="instance">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Instance</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.instance }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>

<mat-paginator
  [pageSize]="10"
  [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 25, 50, 100]"
></mat-paginator>
</mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: (1) can you share screenshot of what is wrong? (2) and what would you like to see... something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-em7xdh ?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly it. I will play around with that.

Comment: I'm using a <mat-card> though.